# Sass can't compile mixin variables

Tags: sass, mixins

I recently purchased a template from templatemonster.com which contains the SASS source.
 I attempted to compile it using `sass --update style.scss` but it stopped and output this :

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...x: #{$postfix}-": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
    on line 7 of custom/mixins/_indent-utilities.scss
```

The offending code is a mixin.
 As I understand it, SASS is constantly changing how it handles variables.
 This error returned with current build 3.4.22.
 At first, I thought maybe something had been deprecated, so I tried a few other arbitrary versions of SASS, but to no avail. 
Unfortunately, the template came with no gemfile, so I have no idea what its dependencies are. 
Here is the offending code :

```
@mixin indent-responsive($prefix, $postfix, $rules, $medias, $offsets) {
  @if ($postfix != '' and $postfix != null) {
    $postfix: #{$postfix}-;
  }

  @if ($prefix != '' and $prefix != null) {
    $prefix: #{$prefix}-;
  }

  @each $resolution, $alias in $medias {
    @if ($resolution == 0) {
      @each $offset in $offsets {
        .#{$prefix}#{$postfix}#{strip-unit($offset)} {
          @each $rule in $rules {
            #{$rule}: $offset;
          }
        }
      }
    } @else {
      @media (min-width: $resolution) {
        @each $offset in $offsets {
          .#{$prefix}#{$alias}-#{$postfix}#{strip-unit($offset)} {
            @each $rule in $rules {
              #{$rule}: $offset;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could offer any insight, I'd super appreciate it!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not handling the string/interpolation right. Try changing this:

```
  @if ($postfix != '' and $postfix != null) {
    $postfix: #{$postfix}-;
  }

  @if ($prefix != '' and $prefix != null) {
    $prefix: #{$prefix}-;
  }
```

to this:

```
  @if ($postfix != '' and $postfix != null) {
    $postfix: $postfix + '-';
  }

  @if ($prefix != '' and $prefix != null) {
    $prefix: $prefix + '-';
  }
```